# Profiling an installed R package with source line numbers?

Tags: r, profiling, data.table

I'd like to profile functions in an installed R package (`data.table`) using `Rprof()` with `line.profiling=TRUE`. Normally, installed package are byte compiled, and line numbers are not available for byte compiled packages.   The usual instructions for line profiling with `Rprof()` require using `source()` or `eval(parse())` so that `srcref` attributes are present.

How can I load data.table so that line numbers are active? My naive attempts to first load the package with `library(data.table)` and then `source('data.table.R')` fails because some of the compiled C functions are not found when I attempt to use the package, presumably because `library()` is using a different namespace. Maybe there is some way to `source()` into the correct namespace?

Alternatively, perhaps I can build a modified version of `data.table` that is not byte compiled, and then load that in a way that keeps line numbers?   What alterations would I have to make, and how would I then load it? I started by setting `ByteCompile: FALSE` and then trying `R CMD INSTALL -l ~/R/lib --build data.table`, but this still seems to be byte compiled.

I'm eager to make this work and will pursue any suggestions. I'm running R 3.2.1 on Linux, have full control over the machine, and can install anything else that is required.

Edit:

**A more complete description of the problem I was trying to solve (and the solution for it) is here: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1249**

I ended up doing essentially what Joshua suggested:  recompile the package with "KeepSource: TRUE" in the DESCRIPTION.   For my purposes, I also found "ByteCompile: FALSE" to be helpful, although this might not apply generally.  I also changed the version number so I could see that I was using my modified version.

Then I installed to a different location with "R CMD INSTALL data.table -l ~/R/lib", and loaded with "library(data.table, lib='~/R/lib')".  When used with the patches given in the link, I got the line numbers of the allocations as I desired.  But if anyone knows a solution that doesn't require recompilation, I'm sure that others would appreciate if you shared.

Comment: The data.table sources are on github https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table  You can clone them, and then use devtools to load the whole package from the sources.  I presume (but have not tested) this will allow you to profile by line numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to get line numbers even if the package is byte-compiled. But, as it says in `?Rprof` (emphasis added):

> Individual statements will be recorded in the profile log if
>   `line.profiling` is `TRUE`, **and if the code being executed was
>   parsed with source references**.  See `parse` for a discussion of
>   source references.  By default the statement locations are not
>   shown in `summaryRprof`, but see that help page for options to
>   enable the display.

That means you need to set `KeepSource: TRUE` either in the `DESCRIPTION` file or via the `--with-keep.source` argument to `R CMD INSTALL`.

Comment: This is promising and will probably work.   Simply adding "KeepSource: TRUE" gets me some of the line numbers, but also adding "ByteCompile: FALSE" seems to get me the rest.   I"m using 'R CMD INSTALL -l ~/R/lib --build data.table' and then 'library(data.table, lib.loc="~/R/lib")'.  I also changed the version number in DESCRIPTION to verify I was using my modified package.   I'll keep experimenting and report back.

Comment: @NathanKurz: Just keep in mind that turning byte-compiling off can make some things a lot less performant (e.g. loops), which might lead you in the wrong direction in your search for bottlenecks.

Comment: @NathanKurz: The file provided to `Rprof` is a text file and can be easily read after profiling. If some function or line of code is on the stack 80% of the time, and therefore is responsible for that 80% of time, then it will be visible on 4 out of 5 samples. So just look at a few randomly selected samples and you will see it. You will also see where it is called from, accounting for that time, and you will see how it spends that time by calling callees. The summarizing tools do not tell you that. Anything you see twice in several samples is a potential bottleneck.

Comment: I confess that I fudged some details to try simplify my question.  In reality, I'm not using Rprof.  Rather, I'm using Rprofmem, which I've patched locally to print line numbers if they are available.  And my goal is to find unnecessary allocations and copies rather than what would normally be considered performance bottlenecks.   Since the allocations reports are precise rather than sampled, Mike's comments about summaries don't come in to play.  And I'm hoping that the allocations will be the same with and without byte compilation, so that Joshua's otherwise valid warning does not apply.

Comment: @NathanKurz: I try to keep quiet about memory profiling, because I don't consider myself an expert in that. It would be interesting to see if similar thinking applies to it, but I've never had the chance to try. I've found memory leaks before, but only by seeing where the leftover blocks came from. I have found excess memory allocations, but that's because they tend to be a performance problem.